# Drop just one column constraint from a composite primary key constraint

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I have a Mysql table having the following structure:

[image]

As you can see there is a composite primary key constraint between the fields: `word_id` and `preposition_id`.

I want to remove the Primary Key constraint from `word_id` without touching the `preposition_id` field, and without losing data from the linked tables (Foreign Key tables). How can I do it?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax available to modify a constraint and drop only "a half" of the primary key.
You must drop the whole primary key, and then recreate it from scrach.
Just:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

and then:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY ( preposition_id );
```

You need first to drop all foreign keys thar reference the primary key in this table.
Data in tables will be preserved.